# how to synchronize module level functions in python

Tags: django, python-2.7, functional-programming, synchronization, unique

I am talking about simple function not class method.

Is the functions in python are synchronize?

Is there any way to maintain the synchronous?

Is python give some built in tool to maintain synchronous state of a function?

there is a number from interface which is user given. We check that it is unique. if it is unique then we will save it in db. but lets two users using this thing and both user give number 10 at that time number 10 is not exist in db. both requests will be created with same number 10 which cause a problem.

A number for same language should not be duplicated.

System allow 10 number for English language and 10 number for Spanish language.but 10 number for English language should not be allowed.

Comment: What issues are you having around async, exactly?

Comment: i have two functions in a file. both create a entry in db. if multiple user access the same function. request will be created with not unique number.

Comment: ...OK? Why do you think there's a *problem*?

Comment: there is a number from interface which is user given. We check that it is unique. if it is unique then we will save it in db. but lets two users using this thing and both user give number 10 at that time number 10 is not exist in db. both requests will be created with same number 10 which cause a problem

Comment: We cannot make unique property in database because my case is that system allow 10 number for English language and 10 number for Spanish language.but 10 number for each language should be unique

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [mcve] rather than a vague description.